# java- Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm trying to make an endpoint using Springboot but im getting this error upon compilation...

"Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase and javax.servlet.ServletContext"

Any suggestions? A google search didnt lead me to the right direction.

```
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_321]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_321]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_321]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_321]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) [spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) [spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:479) [spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211) [spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:184) [spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) [spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) [spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) [spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) [spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) [spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) [spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) [spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) [spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at com.example.HelloWorld.HelloWorldApplication.main(HelloWorldApplication.java:10) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:176) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5147) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_321]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_321]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1319) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    ... 39 common frames omitted

2022-07-07 17:02:17.896 ERROR 1512 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_321]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_321]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) [spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) [spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:479) [spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211) [spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:184) [spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) [spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) [spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) [spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) [spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) [spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) [spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) [spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) [spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at com.example.HelloWorld.HelloWorldApplication.main(HelloWorldApplication.java:10) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:938) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_321]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_321]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_321]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_321]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:176) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5147) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_321]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_321]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1319) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    ... 39 common frames omitted

2022-07-07 17:02:17.896  INFO 1512 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-07-07 17:02:17.899  WARN 1512 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2022-07-07 17:02:17.905  INFO 1512 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-07-07 17:02:17.922 ERROR 1512 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1319)

The following method did not exist:

    javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;

The calling method's class, org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/axf924/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.64/2d91a06d1b93ba13a2cca9e9ea7c143a64037351/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar!/org/apache/catalina/authenticator/AuthenticatorBase.class

The called method's class, javax.servlet.ServletContext, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.8.0_321/lib/ext/servlet-api.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/axf924/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.64/2d91a06d1b93ba13a2cca9e9ea7c143a64037351/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class
    jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.8.0_321/lib/ext/servlet-api.jar!/javax/servlet/ServletContext.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    javax.servlet.ServletContext: file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.8.0_321/lib/ext/servlet-api.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase and javax.servlet.ServletContext
```

build.gradle

````
    
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    
    compileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version: '2.3'
    compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat', name: 'tomcat-catalina', version: '8.5.24'
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Tomcat version 8.5.24 is using Servlet API 3.1, see this : https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

You have to upgrade you servlet-api dependency from 3.0.1 to 3.1

Comment: Or just eliminate the dependency entirely and let the `starter-web` take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your Gradle configuration:

1. These dependencies have conflicting versions, you only need one of them:

```
    compileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version: '2.3'
    compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'
```

2. `servlet-api` dependency with a proper version is already provided by `spring-boot-web-starter`, so you don't need to specify it at all, you can just remove both of those lines.
3. The `tomcat-catalina` dependency is most likely not needed too, since `spring-boot-web-starter` already contains embedded Tomcat, and it's not the best idea to include Tomcat in your compilation classpath anyway. So this line can also be removed:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat', name: 'tomcat-catalina', version: '8.5.24'
```